# XCode keeps lowercasing my file names!

Tags: svn, xcode, macos, version-control

I have OSX installed on a case preserving but not case sensitive partition: 
Which seems to be causing XCode and SVN to fight.

At various points, for reasons I cannot discern, XCode will take a file that has mixed case, and save it in all lowercase to the file system. XCode will continue to display in its file lists the mixes case file.

SVN however is strictly case sensitive reports however will see the lowercase file, so when XCode does a SCM status check the SCM node will list the file twice.

```
? missingfile.cpp
! MissingFile.cpp
```

My only way to fix this is to go with Finder to the file on disk, and rename it from "missingfile.cpp" back to "MissingFile.cpp".

What can I be doing that causes XCode to loose the case of the file? Is this a known bug?

Comment: Which versions of Xcode and OS X are you using?

Comment: mac os x 10.6.3 and xcode 3.2.2

Comment: Is this on a local file system (on an actual HFS+-formatted hard disk), or is it some kind of network volume (e.g. NAS or server or whatever) ?

Comment: boot/primary partition formatted to "Mac OS X Extended (Journaled)".
I'm thinking of repartitioning to create a case sensitive volume on which to continue development. I suspect I might just start to get physically duplicated files that way that could be even worse to diagnose.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but as a point of reference, I (and I'm sure lots of others) use Xcode 3.2.2, OS 10.6.3, and "Mac OS X Extended (Journaled)" disks and have NEVER had this happen.

Comment: @JWWalker: agreed; I think there is a tool being run in the background (that the OP didn't mention or hasn't identified) that is the culprit. It's highly unlikely it's something in core XCode, or thousands of developers would be complaining about it and getting it fixed.

Comment: Its a brand new iMac - factory settings except for the installation of XCode.

Comment: Maybe its because the SVN server is IIS. At any rate the problem stopped since I moved to a case sensitive partition.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest examining the Xcode project file (e.g. `MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`) in a text editor and checking whether it's storing the proper mixed-case filename, or in lower case. If the latter, you could fix the project file manually, and that might fix the problem.

Otherwise, it could be a bug in Xcode - which should probably be reported...

- http://bugreport.apple.com/
- http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/bugrptform.html